# how do i define python's list with dict in grpc's protobuf?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

in .proto:

```
message HelloReplyList { repeated string message = 1; }
```

the following code works fine

```
def SayHelloList(self, request, context):
    l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    return helloworld_pb2.HelloReplyList(message=l)
```

the following code works error:
TypeError: {'a': '1'} has type dict, but expected one of: bytes, unicode

```
def SayHelloList(self, request, context):
    d = [{'a': '1'}, {'b': '2'}]
    return helloworld_pb2.HelloReplyList(message=d)
```

if i want to use `[{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'}]`. how do i define in `.proto`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think protobuf python accept [{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'}].
{'a':'1'} can be a map field in protobuf, [] is a list. We do not support repeated map field.

If the data is {'a':'1', 'b':'2'} then you can define .proto file like:
message HelloReplyList { map map_field = 1; }